# An inequality ouside the unit ball

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

Let $\alpha>0$ and $\phi(x)$ be defined by $\phi(x)=1$ if $|x|<1$ and $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{(1+(|x|^2-1)^4)^\frac{\alpha}{8}}$ for $|x|\geq 1$. Then $|\phi(x)|\leq\frac{c}{|x|^{\alpha}}$ for $|x|\geq 1$ and $|D^2{\phi}|\leq c|x|^{-\alpha}$ for $|x|>1$.

To proceed with the first one, let $|x|=1+\epsilon$ where $\epsilon>0$. Then
$$
1+(|x|^2-1)^4=1+\epsilon^8(1+\frac{2}{\epsilon})^4>\epsilon^8=(|x|-1)^8,
$$
but I need to show the RHS in the above inequality should be $c|x|^8$ for some constant $C$ independent of $x$. Then we can say $|\phi|\leq c|x|^{-\alpha}$ for $x>1$. Can somebody help me with how to proceed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dropped the first term $1$ unnecessarily. If you don't drop it you get LHS $\geq 1+(|x|-1)^{8}$. Let us show that $1+(|x|-1)^{8} \geq 2^{-8}|x|^{8}$. Write $|x|=(|x|-1) +1$ and use the following: $(a+b)^{8} \leq (2 \max \{a,b\})^{8}=2^{8} (\max \{a^{8},b^{8}\})\leq 2^{8}(a^{8}+b^{8})$ with $a=|x|-1, b=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. The second inequality is also fine now.

Comment: Can you kindly have a look at the following question of how to proceed. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3437354/weighted-poincar%c3%a9-inequality-for-lp-function